# Creating batch file from a cmd command

Tags: batch-file, cmd, ping

Made a simple batch file that pings google.com and saves/updates the results to a txt file as it is performing the ping command.

cmd command that works:

```
ping google.com -t > C:\Scripts\PingTestResults.txt
```

I then copied this to a **batch file** and it is showing as this when running it,

```
ping google.com -t 1>C:\Scipts\PingTestResults.txt
```

This results in the ping timing out

I tried removing spaces in between `-t` and the `>` as well as changing location of where the batch file was running from.

Comment: `1>C:\Scipts\PingTestResults.txt` means you redirect the stream number 1 which is stdout. Other streams like stderr and stdin aren't redirected. Anyway your problem wasn't reproducible

Comment: If you don't want that to show, then change it to ```@%SystemRoot%\System32\PING.EXE google.com -t 1>"C:\Scripts\PingTestResults.txt"```.

Comment: By default, batch files _echo their commands_ before executing them. You can suppress this _ad hoc_ for a given command by prepending `@` (e.g. `@ping ...`) or - more typically, for the _entire batch file_ - by using `@echo off` as the first line.